# Finding constant to make function density function

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=cxy$ if $x\geq0 ,y\geq0$ and $x+y\leq1$  and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. Find the value of c such that $f$ becomes a probability density function.

If $f$ is a probability density function then integration of $f$ over $\mathbb R^2$ is 1. So I took limit of $x$ between 0 and $1-y$ and took limit of $y$ between 0and 1 and found the integration which gave me $c=24$. Am I correct or did I made some mistake in integration?

Also what will be the marginal density functions?

Comment: Do you have a formula for the marginal density functions? The first part is correct.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes to find marginal pdf of X we have to take integration of f over y considering x as constant. To find this integral I think I should take limit of y between 0 and 1-x and similar thing to find pdf of Y. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, why don't you try it and tell me the answer?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon $f_X(x)=12x(1-x)^2$ if $0\leq x\leq1$ $f_X(x)=0$ otherwise. And $f_Y(y)=12y(1-y)^2$ if $0\leq y\leq1$ $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Looks good to me!